# cli c++ ComboBox: is there way to add value to items?

Tags: visual-c++

After Searching off some MS docs I found no solution to my case. I need to set additionally Item value to Item name. Value is to be used for IDs. Is there way to do that?

Comment: You can add *any* object to a ComboBox, it does not matter what the class looks like.  But if you care about an "id" then it better have an ID property.  And perhaps override ToString() to generate a meaningful description in the combobox.  Use safe_cast<> in your event handler to cast from object to the class type.

Comment: any example codes?